# convert number of days to a date in C using Jan 1 1990 as an epoch date

Tags: c, epoch

I have a variable which represents a date in number of days since Jan 1 1990. Does anybody know how I can do that? I'm working with MCS 8051, so I can't use any scripts, standard library functions or memory allocation (malloc or calloc). Also this is not a homework. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? What is the epoch on the system, and what numeric types are available for arithmetic?

Comment: I was trying to calculate number of days since Jan 1 1990. The problem is that I'm working on an architecturally old embedded system, so the calculation cannot be computationally intensive. Michał, thanks for trying to help. I talked to a colleague of mine and after a few attempts we figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a tip:

```
$ date --date 'jan 1 1990' +%s
631148400
```

This is the 'epoch date' of Jan 1 1990; expressed in seconds since the Unix epoch. Note this only valid for POSIX systems.

---

Now, that you made it clear that there are no standard library functions available, you'd probably want to use pre-calculated epoch time as a start and add `days * 86400` to it.

Sadly, I guess that you will not have integer types large enough to handle that arithmetic. Since:

```
log(633826800, 2) = approx. 29.23951342
```

You'd need at least 32-bit type to hold the value of the Unix epoch itself.

For example, if you had a 32-bit `uint32_t` type, you could:

```
uint32_t days_to_epoch_date(int days)
{
    uint32_t ret = 631148400L; /* value for Jan 1 1990 */
    ret += 86400 * days;
    return ret;
}
```

If you need to use a different epoch or scale, the values will be different but the method will remain the same. Well, as long as the time measure is linear.

---

*The following example is no longer correct with the new information but I'm leaving it in case anyone being able to use the standard library could find it.*

For the code to be portable, you'd first want to assemble the epoch date in a `struct tm`:

```
#include <time.h>

time_t epoch_time_to_time_t(unsigned int days_since_epoch)
{
    struct tm t = {0};

    t.tm_mday = 1;
    t.tm_mon = 0; /* Jan */
    t.tm_year = 90; /* since 1900 */
    t.tm_isdst = -1;

    /* ... */
}
```

Then, as permitted by *7.23.2.3 The `mktime` function:

> 2 […] The original values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the structure are ignored, and the original values of the other components are not restricted to the ranges indicated above.

…add the number of days to the `struct tm`, and use `mktime()` to obtain the final `time_t`:

```
time_t epoch_time_to_time_t(unsigned int days_since_epoch)
{
    /* ... */

    t.tm_mday += days_since_epoch;

    return mktime(&t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can't use standard libraries, and functions, like time.h and mktime. Everything must be made in house.

Comment: Then I think you need to use the pre-calculated unsigned integer of some kind for the initial value (relative to the epoch) and do arithmetics on that. I'm not sure if you will have integer types large enough, though.

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness: I believe he simply doesn't have the standard library there. Only some minimalistic C cross-compiler.

Comment: Are you answering "convert using 1990 as an epoch", or "convert to a Unix epoch `time_t` value"?

Comment: @aschepler: Well, I judged from the detailed description that the 1990 refers to number-of-days variable, and Unix epoch `time_t` is the target format. Thus, I used that value as an example; the answer, however, can be practically generalized to any other epoch assuming linear time representation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book that collects a huge amount of date and time calculation details and algorithms, that is almost certainly worth checking out. It is supported by source code in standard C (probably C89, certainly not newer).

[Standard C Date/Time Library: Programming the World's Calendars and Clocks](http://amzn.com/0879304960) by Lance Latham, CMP, 1998, ISBN 978-0879304966.

If you needed to start from scratch with date arithmetic, this would be a great resource if only because calenders are full of special cases that are easy to miss.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks like a very nice book. It is sad though that the code is licensed and cannot be used out in the open without the author's permission. If I have time I will definitely try to purchase it or something like it. For some reason the thought haven't even crosses my mind that there might be books on the topic. Thanks again.

Comment: As I recall, I found it originally by browsing the programming section of a physical bookstore, back when there were such things. (The faded price tag still stuck to my copy says "Vroman's Pasadena", which does still exist and is a great bookstore.) I didn't know I needed a book on date arithmetic, but I've been glad of it as a reference on the shelf. I'd suggest contacting to ask what license terms now apply, but also notice that the URL in my copy points to a 404 page now.